# "Too many message types specified in schema definition" when saving Schema

Tags: google-cloud-platform, schema, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to create this protobuf schema in google cloud pub/sub console.

I have a little local script where I successfully serialized and deserialized data with this schema with protobuf.

```
syntax = "proto2";

package mypackage;

message VideoImpression {
    optional string user_id = 1;
    optional string candidate_id = 2;
    optional int64 event_timestamp = 3;
}

message VideoImpressionsList {
    repeated VideoImpression video_impressions = 1;
}
```

When I save the schema I get this error:
`Too many message types specified in schema definition.`

I tried splitting both messages into seperate schema definitions but then it would complaint that e.g. when saving message VideoImpressionsList:
`"VideoImpression" is not defined.`

How can I make pub/sub to accept my above schema with two message types defined?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use one message type inside another, you should define one inside the other like this:

```
syntax = "proto2";

package mypackage;

message VideoImpressionsList {
  message VideoImpression {
    optional string user_id = 1;
    optional string candidate_id = 2;
    optional int64 event_timestamp = 3;
  }
  repeated VideoImpression video_impressions = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I love how active google is on stackoverflow.